# Permission Denied Nginx Docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx

I'm using docker compose to boot up a development workspace, consisting of php, nginx and mysql. Everything boots, static html get's served, but when trying to start a laravel app, i get the following error:

> The stream or file "/home/html/storage/logs/laravel-2019-06-10.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

I searched around and it looked like a permissions issue? Do note, that the docker with just the database and the build in php server does seem to work.

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:

  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

  php-fpm:
    image: php:7.3-fpm-alpine
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - "./:/home/html/"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1-alpine
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    links:
      - php-fpm

    volumes:
      - "./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
      - "./:/home/html/"
```

My nginx config:

```
server {
    index index.php index.html;
    listen 80  default_server;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /home/html/public;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Kind regards :)

Comment: Make sure that the account fastCGI is running under can access the logs folders

Comment: Did you try to change the folder permission ?

Comment: folder permisions should work. My first setup was with the php -S server and that worked. But ill check them to make sure

Comment: Folder permission is 755, so it should be good

Comment: Which container shows this error?

Comment: In addition to the permissions you must assign owner:group to the directory. something like `chown -R $USER:www-data ./storage` or `chown -R $USER:http ./storage`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter the php-fpm container:

```
docker-compose -i -t exec php-fpm /bin/sh
```

Then change access rights of storage folder:

```
chmod -r 777 /home/html/storage
```

Cause it's local development environment, correct rights doesn't matter.